# Laravel 10 and save post that matched logged in user_id

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I want to save a post in my db with the logged user_id.

I have a column user_id in my post table.

When I want to create a new post with this logged user_id nothing happens

Here is my my Route in my web.php :

```
Route::post('posts.index','PostController@store')->middleware(['auth:sanctum']);
```

My model post :

```
protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'content',
        'year',
        'label',
        'number',
        'featured_image',
        'user_id',
    ];

    protected $dates = [
        'created_at',
        'updated_at',
        'date',
    ];
    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
        
    }
}
```

My model user

```
protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
        'password' => 'hashed',
    ];
    public function Posts(): HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Post::class, 'user_id');
    }
}
```

and my Postcontroller :

```
 public function store(StoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
    {
        $post = new Post();
        $user = Auth::user();
        $post->user()->associate($user);
        $post->save();
        
        $validated = $request->validated();

        if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
             // put image in the public storage
            $filePath = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/posts/featured-images', request()->file('featured_image'));
            $validated['featured_image'] = $filePath;
        }
```

I have test many things but I'm lost !

Thank you for your help

Comment: "nothing happens" is an awful description. Do you get a white screen of death? Are any errors logged in your Laravel log? _Something_ happens, not nothing...

Comment: Hello, no errors, my screen stays a the even page = create post,

Comment: It sounds like your form submission isn't happening, in that case. Share the form code as well.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to laravel!

A simple way is to grab the authenticated user as you do and associate the post that you try to store:

```
public function store(StoreRequest $request): RedirectResponse
{
    $validated = $request->validated();

    if ($request->hasFile('featured_image')) {
        $filePath = Storage::disk('public')->put('images/posts/featured-images', request()->file('featured_image'));
        $validated['featured_image'] = $filePath;
    }
    $user = Auth::user();

    $user->posts()->create($validated);
    
    return redirect(); // redirect in your post list
}
```

Check out how the create method works in the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) for the eloquent relationships.

Also, double check that the form you have created is performing a **POST** request to the `route('posts.index')`.